# How to redirect file to another spring controller?

Tags: java, file, spring-mvc, redirect, multipart

I have the following  controller method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "/member/uploadExternalImage",
            "/member/uploadExternalImage" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam String url, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
    ) throws IOException {
        byte[] binaryFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(
                new URL(url)
                        .openStream());

        File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".txt", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, binaryFile);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(file);
        return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
    }
```

Here I get external link, download file by this link and redirect it to the another controller:

It looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/createCompany/uploadImage",
            "/member/uploadImage" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@Validated MultipartFileWrapper file,
            BindingResult result, Principal principal) throws IOException {
```

MultipartFileWrapper:

```
@Component
public class MultipartFileWrapper {
    @Extensions(imageFormats = {".jpg",".png",".gif",".bmp"}, videoFormats = {".mp4",".mov"})
    MultipartFile multipartFile;
    ...
}
```

But redirect doesn't happen properly. It breaks on validation. Accepted multipartFile is null.

How to fix it ?

### P.S.

I tryed this

```
File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".jpg", new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, binaryFile);
        FileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("trololo", ".jpg", false, "fileName", 1024_000_0, file);
        fileItem.getOutputStream();
        fileItem.getInputStream();
        MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
        MultipartFileWrapper wrapper = new MultipartFileWrapper();
        wrapper.setMultipartFile(multipartFile);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(wrapper);
        return "redirect:/member/uploadImage";
```

it redirects correctly but size equals 0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the multipartFile is null because it does not exist in the request. You add a file attribute to the redirect attributes, but that is not going to be bound to the MultipartFileWrapper.

<strike>Try wrapping your file in a CommonsMultipartFile or MockMultipartFile before redirecting.</strike> This was clearly a bad advice since this is no multiform request, and no binding will take place.

The best thing to do would be to handle the file content directly or create a separate method where you handle the file content either it comes from external download or user upload. Then you can add the file as a flash attribute and redirect to this method from both your handleFileUpload methods.

In the common method you will have to pick up the file instance from the model. (like described by Serge Ballesta)

Comment: I have updated my answer, and note that trying to wrap the file was a bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

You add a `File` object as a flash attribute. So you will get it in the Model for the redirected request. But I cannot imagine how you could get it in a `MultipartFile` which is for uploaded files. IMHO your second controller should be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/member/createCompany/uploadImage",
            "/member/uploadImage" })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(Model model, Principal principal) throws IOException {
        File file = (File) model.getAttribute("file");
        ...
```

Comment: I see,  that file size equals 0 before redirect

Comment: @gstackoverflow: I have read, but could not understand what you are trying to achieve. Why do you try to use a MultipartFile for a not uploaded file? Why can't you use directly use the File object or (even better) its content that you have in `binaryFile`?

Answer (score 0):

As shown the code snippet below, just read the file from input stream and write it into the output stream,

```
final File TEST_FILE = new File("C:/Users/arrows.gif");
    final DiskFileItem diskFileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "image/jpeg", true, TEST_FILE.getName(), 100000000, TEST_FILE.getParentFile());
    InputStream input =  new FileInputStream(TEST_FILE);
    OutputStream os = diskFileItem.getOutputStream();
    int ret = input.read();
    while ( ret != -1 )
    {
      os.write(ret);
      ret = input.read();
    }
    os.flush();

    MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(diskFileItem);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("multipartFile", multipartFile);

    return "redirect:request2";
```

In the "request2" mapping method, just get it from model map,

[image]

I hope it should resolve the issue.